# MFC - How to change the position of a dockable pane title position in hidden mode?

Tags: mfc

I have two dockable pane docked on the right side of my main frame that can be hidden.
When they are both auto-hidden, their title pane are closed to each other on the top-right.
Is it possible to change one of pane's position so that it looks like the picture below ?
[image]